# Showing multiple tables on a View page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC6 and Entity Framework 7.

Basically I have 2 main tables.
I want to show table 1 in an enumerated list on the view page and then pull from table 2 while cycling through table 1.

So when I am displaying table 1's data I need to lookup table 2 data that matches the Id of the record.

Here are the 2 models.
School

```
public class School
{
    [Key]
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

Match

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public Season Season { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to pull from the Match table where the SchoolId matches the current school I am displaying and where the SeasonId is the current season which is why I can't link these tables up together. Maybe I am going about the data stucture setup wrong.

Here is the ViewModel I started working on I think I set it up wrong.

```
public class SchoolHomeViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<School> SchoolData { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Match> MatchData { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller code.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new SchoolHomeViewModel();
        vm.SchoolData = _context.Schools;
        vm.MatchData = _context.Matches
            .Where(s => s.SeasonId == 1);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

And finally the View which I can't figure out how to code properly

```
@model IEnumerable<SchoolHomeViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SchoolData)
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MatchData)
}
```

This is where I am getting confused, I know the code is broken and won't run. I need to send a list of Schools and Matches. Cycle through the schools first then cycle through the Matches within the Schools to display that accordingly.

Comment: Your view is expecting an IEnumerable of SchoolHomeViewModel but you are passing it only a single SchoolHomeViewModel object.

Comment: This is where I am getting confused, I need to send a list of Schools and Matches. Cycle through the schools first then cycle through the Matches withing the Schools to display that accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's get your view to accept the correct ModelType, a single ScholHomeViewModel instead of an IEnumerable.  This is the model declaration at the top of the View.

```
@model PTPWebApp.ViewModels.Schools.SchoolHomeViewModel
```

Since you no longer have your model declared as a list, no sense in doing the foreach loop, but instead SchoolData and MatchData are lists themselves. So let's rework what we are doing in your loop:

```
<table>
<th><td>School ID</td><td>School Name</td></th>
    @foreach (var school in item.SchoolData)
    {
       @<tr>
            <td>@school.SchoolId</td>
            <td>@school.SchoolName</td>
       </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much this got the school info to start showing up. Now for the Match data. Do I open another foreach within there and check if the schoolids match then display? I tried but it throws an error saying I already have an open DataReader.

Comment: Nevermind I added MultipleActiveResultSets=true to my connection string and it worked. Thanks again!